# Redshift - How to identify low performing areas in Query?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, query-performance

**Background**: I am new to Redshift and PostgreSQL and would like to know how to improve the performance of my queries. I would need feedback in terms of either ***execution time***, *amount of memory used* or other relevant metrics from the queries I run.

**Question**: Is there a simple SQL command/method(?) to have (at least a rough idea) of which areas in a query takes the most time to execute?

**Additional info**: I often use Common Table Expressions like this:

```
WITH level1 as (SELECT Customerid 
                FROM customer_tbl
                WHERE year > 2000), 
level2 as (SELECT level1.Customerid,
                  purchasing_tbl.item,
                  purchasing_tbl.price
           FROM level1
           LEFT JOIN purchasing_tbl
                  ON purchasing_tbl.id = level1.Customerid
```

Usually this type of structure may have more than 10 levels, that usually include is a lot more cumbersome (in terms of more joins, where, case, window functions with different aggregations).

*When trying to improve performance it would help to know e.g. how much time level10 took to execute compared to level2.*

**Client**: I use the DBeaver 5.1.1.

Comment: In Postgres you could use `explain (analyze) ...` but I think that's not available in Redshift

Comment: Yes, EXPLAIN <sql> is valid in Redshift. Here is a good starting point: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-the-query-plan.html     and   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_EXPLAIN.html

Comment: Some more options for examining query plans - estimated vs actual, including TIMING:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/analyzing-query-execution.html   AND   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-analyzing-the-query-summary.html  These list some system views which I've also found to be helpful.

Comment: @VictorDiLeo Seems like what I am looking for! You wouldn't happen to use it e.g. on "level2" in the example and put as an answer? Most likely I would be able to give you credit for that reply.

Comment: couple of things to note : In redshift, cte's are not materialised. its just a shortcut for nesting (sometimes ctes can be very expensive uless you realise what is being generated). and also - make sure that you run your sql a second time (to avoid counting compile time) and are not using a cached result in redshift.

Comment: An excellent point about CTEs. I am seeing them used more often without a real understanding of what they do and don't do.

Answer (score 0):

STL_QUERY is a sytem view in Redshift that contains query timings:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_QUERY.html

select starttime, enddtime, * from stl_query where querytxt = ''
order by starttime desc
limit 100 ;

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to know the sub optimal queries.

Below link provides different steps to check the same.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-performance-improvement-opportunities.html#suboptimal-data-distribution

There are some utilities given by AWS - which are available in GIT Hub.

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils

Both of these materials are very useful in tuning the queries.

Regards,
Rama